# In what order does Scheme code run?

Tags: runtime, scheme, operator-precedence

We've been taught various syntax and told how to write definitions, but we've never written any code an ran it. What is the order that Scheme code runs in?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Try posting some example and asking specific questions?

Comment: For example, in java the main method is ran first and like wise in C the main() is called. In Scheme nothing like this exists (to my knowledge) so which part of the program runs first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but if you're asking about which evaluation strategy scheme uses:

Scheme uses [applicative order evaluation](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node85.html).

Edit: Ok, that wasn't what you were asking. So here is the answer to your question as I understand it now:

Scheme code is executed top-to-bottom: I.e. the first expression in the file is executed first, then the one beloew that, then the one below that and so one until the end of file is reached.

So if you have a file containing:

```
(display "hello ")
(display "world\n")
```

Then `(display "hello ")` is executed first and then `(display "world\n")`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I cannot believe we have not been taught this!

Comment: @Alex: Since you'll probably run most of your code from the REPL instead of creating runnable programs, knowing how to create runnable programs isn't really as essential as in other languages.

Comment: For the record, MOST scripting languages are run top-to-bottom, since they don't have specific entry points like "main", but in many languages, function definitions are allowed to occur anywhere.

Comment: note that scheme allows the arguments to be evaluated in any order i.e. whether `((lambda (a b) #f) (display "1") (display "2"))` prints `12` or `21` is undefined by the standard.